# ¿Cómo mostrar cada fase del algoritmo?

Tags: java

Tengo este código , y me gustaría mostrar una traza de como se va ejecutando el algoritmo , osea su resultado.

```
public static Double abc(int x,int n,double ac){
    Double d = null;

    if(n==0){ 
        d = ac;
    }else{
        d= abc(x, n-1, (ac+(x/ac))/2);

    }
    return d;
}
```

He probado esto:

```
 for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
    double[] fases = d[i];
 }
```

Pero no es correcto , alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a mostrar el resultado de la variable `d` en cada momento entonces lo puedes hacer directamente con `System.out.println` después de cada sentencia en la cual le cambies el valor a dicha variable.

```
public static Double abc(int x,int n,double ac){
    Double d = null;
    System.out.println(d); //Va a devolver null
    if(n==0){ 
        d = ac;
        System.out.println(d); //Si n == 0 devolverá este valor de d
    }else{
        d= abc(x, n-1, (ac+(x/ac))/2);
        System.out.println(d); //Si n != 0 devolverá este otra valor de d
    }
    return d;
}
```

Por último, te faltaría mostrar el resultado una vez llames a la función abc.

```
Double resultado = abc(1, 0, 2.0);
System.out.println(resultado);
```